# error - cannot import name 'DataType' from 'pyspark.sql.types'

Tags: python, pyspark, pycharm

why in pycharm , all codes working a hour ago are giving errors now for normal run while same codes are running in debugging mode of pycharm?? it is showing error like this in normal run-
cannot import name 'DataType' from 'pyspark.sql.types'

i tried but couldnt find anything

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

it shown such error because my file name was json.py
but spark.sql also has such class so python interpretor got confused and it thrown error.
solution - changed name of file